# How can I customise the toolbar in the new iWork apps?

Tags: macos, iwork

Since the update to the iWork app suite, it appears that it is no longer possible to customise the toolbar with option from the right-click menu. All you can do is hide the text, or hide the entire toolbar:

[image]

In addition, you can't ⌘-drag any of the toolbar buttons, whether that be to different places on the toolbar, or off the toolbar completely…

I really want to remove the Tips <sub>[image]</sub> button, as well as re-arrange some things to make it more like how I had iWork '09 set up.

Is there a Terminal command or other preference to re-enable the customisation of the toolbar, or at the least a command to forcibly remove the Tips button from the toolbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in Pages 5.0.1, Numbers 3.0.1 and Keynote 6.0.1.

[image]